# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Pets breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3          8
Users destroyed                                  31          0
Users contacted                                   8          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           144        297
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                8         36
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         18         99
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                7        295
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                22      1,013
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               39        158
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          0
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               15          1
Questions protected                              12         41
Questions migrated                                6          0
Questions flagged⁴                                5         84
Questions closed                                309         25
Question flags handled⁴                          64         25
Posts unlocked                                    3          4
Posts undeleted                                  27          6
Posts locked                                      3         49
Posts deleted⁵                                  414        217
Posts bumped                                      0        424
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               17          0
Comments flagged                                  3        197
Comments deleted⁶                               715        283
Comment flags handled                           114         86
Answers flagged                                  79        515
Answer flags handled                            532         62
All comments on a post moved to chat              2          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...